# changing the matrix value according to intervals of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, intervals, bin

I want to make an interval from 3 to 10.5 into 4 continuous bins. Then, I want to use them as column names and set some numbers as the value of these columns like below:

```
df<-read.table(text="name1   name2    (3,4.5)     (4.5,6)     (6,7.5)     (7.5,9) (9,10.5)
               a_fgh   l_opu   10  -31 75  50  -69 
               c_dfg   a_fgh   45  60  30  33  38
               p_opu   c_dfg   75  57  40  22  -63
               l_opu   c_dfg   -69 -56 78  96  78
               ",
               header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE,row.names = NULL)
```

In the next step, I want to use these values to change the values of another matrix like below.

```
mat<-read.table(text="     a_fgh   c_dfg   l_opu
                           a_fgh   0   3.5  7
                           c_dfg 3.5  0   8.5
                           l_opu 7  8.5  0",
                header=TRUE)
mat2<-as.matrix(mat)
```

In this case, the value between a_fgh   and l_opu is equal to 7 and regarding the bin is between (6,7.5), however in the df according to it's two first two columns should be -69, so the value of the matrix should be changed to -69. So the desired output would be like this:

```
                                 a_fgh   c_dfg   l_opu
                           a_fgh   0   45  75
                           c_dfg 45  0   96
                           l_opu 75  96  0
```

Any idea about it? I don't know what to do at all.

Comment: The rows in your `table` (by the way, do not name your objects exactly like base functions!) are of different length. Please revise your data example, and optimally use `dput()` to provide it.

Comment: FYI, `table` is a pre-existing function in R. It is highly recommended that you don't use names already being utilized.

Comment: You have more values than column names starting from the second row. Not to mention that such column names are a very bad practice in the first place.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I know, the colnames are bad, but in this case I don't have any better idea

Comment: @DavidArenburg the dataframe is much larger than the matrix values.

Comment: But you still missing values `df`. Try reading `df` into R

Comment: @DavidArenburg You'r right, I fixed it.

Comment: Now you have not enough column names. The first column was converted to row names. You will also need to specify `, check.names = FALSE`, otherwise your column names will be useless

Comment: You need to add a new column names of `(9,10.5)` or such. Otherwise all your values are shifted and the `name2` column gets numercic values. Also, your desired output isn't clear, please provide it for the data you have.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I fixed it. My data set is extremely huge and I can not paste it here.

Comment: I mean that you need to show the desired output for the example data you've provided. Not the your whole data.